# How do methods of inner classes affect fields in the enclosing class?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I have an example in which I try to create an android app that sends messages over wifi using sockets. The following code compiles, but raises a NullPointerException when executing the code in the send button onclicklistener. I would expect that the code in class ClientThread would actually make the field 'socket' of MainActivity point to the newly opened Socket, but when I try to open the DataOutPutStream 'socket' still seems to point to null. Why can an instance of my innerclass not change what the field socket points to?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Socket socket;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText ipText = findViewById(R.id.ipText);
    final EditText msgText = findViewById(R.id.msgText);
    Button sendbtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button ipbtn = findViewById(R.id.ipbtn);

    sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(msgText.getText().toString());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    ipbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            new Thread(new ClientThread(ipText.getText().toString())).start();
        }
    });
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable{
    String ip;
    private ClientThread(String address){
        ip = address;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, 80);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

When running I make sure to press the ipbtn first, so the code in ClientThread.run() should have ran.